# Determine maximum and minimum acceleration from v(t)

Tags: calculus

So I have the formula:

$v(t) = 0.001302t^3 - 0.09029t^2 +23.61t - 3.083$

**Determine the minimum and maximum acceleration in the interval:** $t ∈ [0,126] s$

So I know that $v'(t) = a(t)$  so $a(t) = 3(0.001302)t^2 - 2(0.09029)t + 23.61$

So now I know that I can find the minimum acceleration at $a'(t) = 0$ and solving that I find that $t < 0$ so that tells me the minimum is at 0s which I can plug in to find minimum, and because of that I know that maximum is at 126s.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes.  That's right.

Comment: Check your calculations for $a'(t) = 0$.  It occurs for a positive value of $t$.  In fact, it occurs within the interval $[0, 126]$, so you will have to check the relative extremum and both endpoints.

Comment: @Mathemagical  The claim that $a'(t) = 0$ when $t < 0$ is false.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your calculation of $a'(t)$.

Comment: Right.  Please do that, OP. @N.F.Taussig.  I'd just checked that min and max are 0 and 126 respectively.  (by computing a, which doesn't have an interior max in the interval, just monotonically increases)

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah I turned a + sign into a - sign by accident! That's why it isn't correct!

Answer (score 1):

$a(t)=v'(t)=0.003906 t^2-0.18058 t+23.61$

The acceleration is minimum when $a'(t)=0\land a''(t)>0$

$a'(t)=0.007812 t-0.18058$

$a'(t)=0$ for $t_0=23.1157$s

$a''(t)=0.007812>0$ thus $t_0$ is a local minimum

as the derivative  $a(t)$ is positive for $t>t_0$ the acceleration is increasing so the minimum is also a global minimum.

Furthermore we can observe that $a(t)$ is the equation of a parabola with concavity up, therefore the local minimum is also the global minimum

Hope this helps

Comment: Since the question asks for the minimum and maximum on a closed interval, I would stress that the OP needs to check the value of the acceleration at both endpoints and compare them with the relative minimum in order to find the global extrema.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $a(t)$ is the equation of a parabola with concavity up. Its local minimum is also the global minimum...